# Filtering from array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I am trying to filter a few items out of an array. So far I have been able to filter an item in the array, but if I want to remove a child from the array element I am unable to do so.
In the example below `chartsArray` has code value `Age_Total`. In  array `el` I have this string `Age_Total` and when I filter it is removed. But I also have a field `Q0120F_18P` which doesn't get filtered. You can still see this element in the fourth array element under `Age_Female` . So my question is how can I iterate through `chartsArray` where it can filter the parent array element as well as the child element.

https://jsfiddle.net/snt/n16pfgbk/

Comment: The thing is you have multiple levels of nesting there. How many levels should you check?

Comment: As of now I have face 2 levels ,it might go up to 3 at certain level if the data changes(might)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could filter the children with a recursive call and assign it inside of the filter callback.

```
chartsArray = chartsArray.map(a => a.filter(function code(o) {
    if (!el.includes(o.code)) {
        if (o.children) {
            o.children = o.children.filter(code);
        }
        return true;
    }
}));
```